# Memory leak with SWIG, Python and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, python, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2012, swig

This is my first experience with Python, so bear with me:  I'm getting a memory leak of 28 bytes when I reference a SWIG module with a c++ class in it.  All of this is being built and run in Visual Studio 2012.  My .cpp file for the module is empty and my header is as follows:

```
class foo{
public:
  foo() {}
  virtual ~foo() {}
};
```

Here's the .i file for SWIG:

```
%module SwigTest2
%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "SwigTest2.h"
%}
%include "SwigTest2.h"
```

Finally, here's the code I'm using to embed this module from c++:

```
  Py_Initialize();
  PyObject* pPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");
  if(pPath)
  {
    CString csScriptFolder("C:\\Testing\\Debug");
    PyList_Append(pPath, PyUnicode_FromString(csScriptFolder));
    CString csPath("multiply");
    PyObject* pName = PyUnicode_FromString(csPath);
    if(pName != NULL)
    {
      PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
      Py_DECREF(pName);
      if (pModule != NULL)
      {
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
      }
    }
  }
  Py_Finalize();
```

When I run this everything goes through fine except for the memory leak.  If I put real code in the module it works fine but still leaks the 28 bytes on exit.  If I add another class to the module I get another 28 byte leak.  If I run the module 3 times I get 3 leaks, so if I had 2 classes in the module I would wind up with 6 total leaks of 28 bytes each.

One possibility (aside from my general cluelessness on Python) is that I'm linking to the release build of Python while building debug versions of my c++ module and c++ executable.  The other thing is that if I remove the class definition and use plain old functions the memory leak goes away and everything works fine.

Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure.. but I had similar Problem with Visual Studio 2012 and Iron-Python 2,7. The script was correct and had no problem when running with a Python interpreter. But I read that in some cases Visual Studio can't find the reference in the memory... (guess that’s the memory lack) But when I ran the Python file over a C# Python Run-time It worked... I guess it's a compiler based problem. S0rry if this was not helpful.

Comment: That's what I was wondering - I ran the same type of thing in Visual Studio 2010 and had many more memory leaks.  Apparently it had something to do with global memory allocation that wasn't really leaking, studio was just picking it up as such.  It was fixed in 2012, so I thought maybe this was something similar.

Comment: I was able to get past this by setting the Runtime Library to "Multi-Threaded DLL" instead of "Multi-Threaded Debug DLL".  Debugging works but the memory leak is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this by setting the Runtime Library to "Multi-Threaded DLL" instead of "Multi-Threaded Debug DLL". Debugging works but the memory leak is gone.  Sorry for the duplicate post...